# Edit Content in <head></head> in Joomla 2.5.6

Tags: joomla

It's been some time since I worked in Joomla. I'm trying to edit specific code that's between the  section on a Joomla 2.5.6 site. The site was created by someone else, so I'm  not sure how or what (maybe a plugin? or in the theme?) they used to add the head content in.

Here is the site:

http://healkidneydisease.com

And here is the code that I'm trying to change:

```
<!-- ClickBank Trust Badge -->
<script src="//cbtb.clickbank.net/?vendor=holistic10"></script>
```

All I really need to do is change "holistic10" to "holistic08".

I would think it would be easy, but I can't seem to find where this text is located in the back end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Look in your template index.php file.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elin, but I didn't see much there, just an If, Else statement in PHP.

I'm beginning beginning to think it may be a plugin or something.. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello, Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at StackExchange. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you ask your question there. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Rishi, I may do that.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question via a self-accepted answer so this is marked as answered and doesn't come up in searches for open q's